# How can I detect device touch support in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

In the past, when detecting whether a device supports touch events in JavaScript, we could do something like this:

```
var touch_capable = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
```

However, Google Chrome (17.x.x+) returns `true` for the above check, even if the underlying device does not support touch events. For example, running the above code on Windows 7 returns true, and thus if we combine it with something like:

```
var start_evt = (touch_capable) ? 'ontouchstart' : 'onmousedown';
```

On Google Chrome, the event is never fired since we're binding to `ontouchstart`. In short, does anyone know a reliable way to circumvent this? I am currently running the following check:

```
var touch_capable = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') == -1)
```

Which is far from ideal...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct answer is to handle *both* event types - they're not mutually exclusive.

For a more reliable test for touch support, also look for `window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch` which is one of the tests used by [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/touchevents.js)

Better yet, just use Modernizr yourself and have it do the feature detection for you.

Note though that you cannot prevent false positives, hence my first line above - you've *got* to support both.

Comment: Correct - while I have (and love) a tablet PC, sometimes I have a mouse and I'm not afraid to use it.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually for a jQuery plugin, and I'd rather not add the pre-requisite of Modernizr too. However, for some reason `window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch` returns `undefined`...

Comment: @BenM you do know it's possible to build a custom download of Modernizr that'll include only the tests you need?

Comment: Yes, I do. However, if you look at the test they perform in Modernizr (i.e. `('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch`), that will return `true` for Chrome 17.x.x+ since the first evaluation is true...

Comment: @BenM "undefined" is the expected result for that test on desktop Chrome.  Take a look at the Modernizr source module I linked to.

Comment: @BenM yes, and that's why I said you have to handle _both_ types of event.

Comment: Thank you, I will handle both events, as it seems like the best approach.

Answer (score 16):

This is a modification of how Modernizr performs touch detection, with added support to work with IE10+ touch devices.

```js
const isTouchCapable = 'ontouchstart' in window ||
 (window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof window.DocumentTouch) ||
 navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ||
 window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;
```

It's not foolproof since [detecting a touch device is apparently an impossibility](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/).

Your mileage may vary:

- Older touchscreen devices only emulate mouse events
- Some browsers & OS setups may enable touch APIs when no touchscreen is connected, for example, in systems where a driver for a touchscreen is installed, but the touch hardware is not functioning or not installed.
- In a hybrid mouse/touch/trackpad/pen/keyboard environment, this doesn't indicate which input is being *used*, only that the browser detects touch hardware present. For example, a user could switch from using a mouse to touching the screen on a touch-enabled laptop or mouse-connected tablet at any moment. It only detects if the browser believes it *could* accept or emulate a touch input, for example, when using mobile emulation mode in Chrome Dev Tools.

**Update:**
A tip: Do not use touch-capability detection to control & specify UI behaviors, [use event listeners instead](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/03/better-browser-input-events/). Design for the click/touch/keyup event, not the device, touch-capability detection is typically used to save the cpu/memory expense of adding an event listener. One example of where touch detection could be useful and appropriate:

```
if (isTouchCapable) {
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', myTouchFunction, false); 
}
```

And... bonus, you can test this code in your browser by running the code snippet below.

```js
const isTouchCapable = 'ontouchstart' in window ||
 (window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof window.DocumentTouch) ||
 navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ||
 window.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0;
const qualifier = isTouchCapable ? "IS" : "is NOT";
alert(`Your browser/device ${qualifier} currently capable of recieving touch events.`)
```

Comment: Work for me, Thanks!

Comment: @Benson: Thx! This works for most browsers but I noticed that it unfortunately does not work for Chrome 65.0.3325.181 on Windows 10. When using a Lenovo Thinkpad T460 (non-touchscreen) the statement returns true.

Comment: @user2718671 I tested this on Windows 10 with a non-touchscreen laptop with Chrome 65.  The only way I can get it to report that the device has touch capability is if I use device emulation for a mobile device. When you have Chrome Inspector open, make sure you're not in a touch emulation mode by checking that your cursor is the "arrow" and not the "finger shadow" dot.

Comment: @Benson: Yes, I know. Touch emulation wasn't enabled. Maybe this is just a special case. I think it's because there is also a Lenovo Thinkpad T460 with touchscreen and there are just some drivers or some hidden hardware components that make Chrome believe it's a touchscreen. It's really strange anyway :D

Comment: @user2718671 Gotcha. I'm guessing it's the first statement `"ontouchstart" in window` that Chrome is reporting true? Perhaps there's some touch property proves it is not, in fact, touch capable to prevent the false positive, we could add it to the logic chain.  If you find what that property might be, please share.

Comment: @Benson: I'm not sure if such a statement could be possible... Anyway 'ontouchstart' in window and also navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 return true.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the well tested (and cross-browser) Modernizr's touch test.

*From their site:*

```
// bind to mouse events in any case

if (Modernizr.touch){
   // bind to touchstart, touchmove, etc and watch `event.streamId`
}
```

http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html

Comment: right sentiment, wrong answer.  Modernizr can test "false positive" for touch support, so you should still always support mouse events too.

Comment: Apart from that, it's not good to _force_ the user to use their touch screen (instead of thee mouse they're holding).

Comment: Yeah, should always include mouse support and include touch support if the device supports. Need to correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well old question, but having to do this without a library, I created the following solution -- simply let the events talk for them self -- when you see the `touch` events, just disable the processing of the `mouse` events.

In coffescript is would look like this;

```
           hasTouch = false
           mouseIsDown = false
           @divs.on "touchstart", (e)->
              hasTouch = true
              touchstart(e.timeStamp,e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX);
              return true
           @divs.on "mousedown", (e)->
              mouseIsDown = true;
              touchstart(e.timeStamp,e.clientX) if not hasTouch
              return true

           @divs.on 'touchmove', (e) ->
              touchmove(e.timeStamp,e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX);
              return true;
           @divs.on 'mousemove', (e) ->
              touchmove(e.timeStamp,e.clientX) if mouseIsDown and not hasTouch 
              return true;

           @divs.on 'touchend', (e) ->
              touchend();
              return true
           @divs.on 'mouseup', (e) ->
              mouseIsDown = false;
              touchend() if not hasTouch
              return true
```

The just define functions for `touchstart`,`move` and `end` containing the actual logic....