# How to eliminate pointer events, but not touch events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, touch

Setting `pointer-events:none` seems to also turn off touch events. This obviously doesn't make sense, because "touch" events aren't "pointer" events. My finger is not a pointer. :)

Is there some way to turn off *only* pointer/mouse events, but leave touch events alone? A property like `touch-events` would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable only mouse events through CSS. But you can easily do it with javascript:

- Check touch support by using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or simply see a discussion about touch detection [How can I detect device touch support in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439903/how-can-i-detect-device-touch-support-in-javascript)
- If touch events are not supported, apply a CSS class (you previously created) or directly add the CSS rule on all the elements you want to ignore pointer events.

Comment: This seems completely unreliable and subject to change. Sucks there's no official spec for distinguishing such things.

Comment: It can look frustrating maybe, but this is a quite reliable solution. Web and frontend development is often a hacker's job :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, a touch event is a specific type of pointer event based on the definition.

From [W3.org, Pointer Events, Section 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-pointerevents-20130219/#intro)

> A pointer can be any point of contact on the screen made by a mouse
>   cursor, pen, touch (including multi-touch), or other pointing input
>   device.

Also:

> The events for handling generic pointer input look a lot like those
>   for mouse: pointerdown, pointermove, pointerup, pointerover,
>   pointerout, etc. This facilitates easier content migration from Mouse
>   Events to Pointer Events. Pointer Events provide all the usual
>   properties present in Mouse Events (client coordinates, target
>   element, button states, etc.) in addition to new properties for other
>   forms of input: pressure, contact geometry, tilt, etc. So authors can
>   easily code to Pointer Events to share logic between different input
>   types where it makes sense, and customize for a particular type of
>   input only where necessary to get the best experience.

[image]

So, setting `pointer-events:none;` will affect both touch and mouse events.

So to answer your question; you can't distinguish between `mouse events` (I assume by `pointer events` in your question you basically meant `mouse events`) and `touch events` with css only and the `pointer-events` property. But since `mouse events` and `touch events` are different, you can revert to javascript for your needs in this case.