# How can I target devices with touch screens / no mouse?

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media (hover: none) {
  main {
    a {
      display: none;

    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code I've tried, but it doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: What do you want to happen when you "hover"?

Comment: I just want to hide the button when on a mobile phone/tablet touchscreen

Comment: What browser are you testing on? I'm assuming this is written in a preprocessor since you can't nest style rules in traditional CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Though not *directly* possible to detect if a mouse exists (touchscreen laptops can still have a mouse, after all), there is a media query available!

```
@media (pointer: coarse) {
  /* rules */
}
```

This detects if a coarse pointer (such as a finger) is currently the *primary* device. If you want to check if *any* of the devices are coarse, you can use the following.

```
@media (any-pointer: coarse) {
  /* rules */
}
```

If you're trying to target devices that *aren't* touchscreen or similar, use `pointer: fine` or `any-pointer: fine`.

Additionally, there is `@media (hover)`, though Firefox does not currently support this (per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover)).

Edit: Upon closer inspection, it looks like Firefox doesn't support `pointer` or `any-pointer` either ☹

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those areas where Firefox is needlessly falling behind. Also, I wonder why the spec still considers any-pointer/any-hover at risk. There have been not two but *three* independent implementations of the feature for a few years.

Comment: @BoltClock If I had to guess (by looking at the spec), it's because `any-hover` has no implementations, and they're listed together. Chrome is listed as in development for it.

Comment: So it sounds like it's not a good idea to use since firefox wont support it. Does anyone know of a JS library that will do this easily?

Comment: @stackers See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439903/how-can-i-detect-device-touch-support-in-javascript).